# Issue parsing date format M/D/YYYY

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a string date in the format `M/D/YYYY` and I'm trying to format it into a `new Date()` date. I've tried the following and it's printing out `Invalid Date`.

```
console.log(date)
console.log(moment(date, "MM/DD/YYYY").toDate())
console.log(moment(date, "M/D/YYYY").toDate())

3/10/2017
2017-10-03T04:00:00.000Z
2017-10-03T04:00:00.000Z

3/13/2017
Invalid Date
Invalid Date
```

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js

This parses correctly without anything but throws a massive warning.

```js
var date = '2/23/2017';
console.log(moment(date, "MM/DD/YYYY").toDate())
console.log(moment(date, "M/D/YYYY").toDate())

var date = '3 / 13 / 2017';
console.log(moment(date, "MM/DD/YYYY").toDate())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```

```
console.log(moment(date).toDate())
```

Comment: why don't you just use `new Date(date);`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue with lastest version, can you provide a snippet or fiddle showing you problem? Which version of moment are you using? In which browser/environment?

Comment: Converting your code to a runnable snippet shows it does not throw any errors. Voting to close as "unable to reproduce".

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this `moment(date, "MM/DD/YYYY").toDate();`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Date.parse` like the following:

```
new Date(Date.parse(date));
new Date(Date.parse("2017-10-03T04:00:00.000Z"));
// > Tue Oct 03 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

You can then use the built-in browsers functions `.getDate()`, `.getMonth()`, `.getFullYear()` /etc. to get the attributes of the above

```
var myDate = new Date(Date.parse(date));
console.log(myDate.getMonth())
```

Comment: `new Date(Date.parse(string))` is **identical** to `new Date(string)`, but parsing strings with the built-in parser using either Date.parse or new Date is not recommended due to browser variances.

Answer (score -1):

This works!

```
moment(date, "l").toDate()
```

Comment: An answer should explain the OP's problem and how your answer fixes it.